# Logarithmic Depth Map

Tags: rendering, unity, depth-map

Would someone know how to create a logarithmic depth map where the precision level decreases the further away you get from the near plane? It seems like the Z Pass in Blender's render layer node only outputs linear depth values.

I will be using this depth map to replace Unity's camera depth texture (which is also logarithmic.)

Any help would be highly appreciated, thank you!